# Как послать сигнал нажатия средней кнопки мыши после нажатия на правую?

Tags: linux

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на правую кнопку мыши вместе с ней нажималась средняя.

Я пробовал различные трюки с xdotool, xte и xbindkeys, ничего не получается. Проблема в том, что когда xbindkeys получает новую команду для кнопки мыши, он забывает о её изначальном назначении. Я легко могу заменить функции клавиш или поменять их местами, но никак не могу добавить свою команду к функции клавиши по умолчанию.

Comment: даже интересно стало: а что же этот ваш загадочный x-клиент должен сделать при получении сигнала об одновременном нажатии правой и средней кнопки манипулятора? // подозреваю, что вам надо начать с отключения эмуляции нажатия средней кнопки при одновременном нажатии правой и левой кнопок манипулятора (нынче по умолчанию в дистрибутивах именно так конфигурируется x-сервер).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin мне не обязательно одновременно, можно и поочерёдно. У меня тут игра, в которой камера вращается зажатием средней кнопки мыши, а контекстные действия через правую. Это во-первых очень неудобно, во-вторых я сломал себе уже две мыши, постоянно зажимая колесо. Хочу объединить/совместить вращение камеры и контекстные действия на правую кнопку.